# Help explain this long sentence in simple way

Tags: expressions, sentence

""whoever makes two blades of grass or two ears of corn grow where only one grew before serves mankind better than the whole race of politicians" ."

Thanks

Comment: What do you think it means?

Comment: @HotLicks nice Q :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's an age old sentiment that politicians are, generally, worthless!

Any (one) person who can make something (such as farming) more productive or efficient (like growing 2 corns instead of 1) is better for mankind than all politicians put together.